# Build failed - h3

Tags: python, build, pip, uber-api, h3

Installing h3 throws back an error

```
pip install h3
```

Error log when trying to install h3 (uber-api). Building failed is what I got in multiple attempts. Try to help me with some solution

```
Collecting h3
Using cached h3-3.7.3.tar.gz (17.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: h3
Building wheel for h3 (PEP 517) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'D:\Softwares\MiniConda\envs\scstv16-master\python.exe' 
'D:\Softwares\MiniConda\envs\scstv16-master\lib\site-

packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C
:\Users\Samar\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmkh239s9'
       cwd: C:\Users\Samar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hfkw98sf\h3_a82b52f712ae41309ab8ffcfabd0f09b
  Complete output (293 lines):
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Samar/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-hfkw98sf/h3_a82b52f712ae41309ab8ffcfabd0f09b/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
..........
..........
..........
..........
Failed to build h3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h3 which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Help to find the solution ✌️

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: "*Help to find the solution…*" What have you searched?